# What do these Microsoft Updates do, and why can't they configure correctly?

Tags: boot, installation, windows-update, sql-server

```
MB:      Biostar M7NCG 400  
CPU:     AMD Athlon XP 2200+ 1.8GHz  
RAM:     2.5GB (I don't know the speed, but does it really matter?)  
Display: NVidia GeForce 4 TI 4200, with hardware support for DirectX 8  
OS:      Microsoft Windows XP SP3
```

**Four days ago I installed the following, in a single update cycle:**

```
Update for Root Certificates [November 2009] (KB931125)  
Update for Windows XP (KB976098)  
Update for Microsoft XML Core Services 4.0 Service Pack 2 (KB973688)  
Update for Windows XP (KB973687)  
Update for Windows XP (KB971513)  
Update for Internet Explorer 8 Compatibility View List for Windows XP (KB975364)
```

My experience with Microsoft Update is that the computer will boot and log-in slower than usual when you restart the first time - but the computer will usually return to its original speed and booting-time after the update is complete. I believe this is simply due to the fact that the computer has more tasks to perform than usual, on boot and on log-in after an update cycle - namely, configuring software updates to files that were in use by another process when the updates were downloaded and installed.

Still with me? :-)

After I installed that batch of updates four days ago, my computer did the usual stuff and booted slower on the initial restart. I could see by my HDD light that the computer had quite a bit more work to do on boot, as expected.

When I logged in, the following was displayed before my desktop finished initializing:

[image]

This is also familiar to me, and seems appropriate for the situation.

One would expect these events to occur on the first restart after installing updates. However, it is expected that the computer would boot normally from that point on, without any extra configurations being performed. But my computer keeps booting the same way, as if it never succeeds in configuring the installed updates.

Every time my computer boots, it spends a noticable amount of time working, far more than usual or necessary. And every time I log-in, the same two windows appear, saying that it is "Setting up personalized settings..."

The event log shows the following *Application* event has occured during the log-in process:

[image]

This error did not occur before the updates were installed, but has occured on every log-in since.

I haven't used SQL Server Express much, but it is a prerequisite for the development software I use. The server starts automatically every time I boot my computer, so I don't see how restarting the server would solve the problem.

That's all the information I can think of at the moment. I need to know what those updates are supposed to accomplish, and how to recover from this error so that the updates can be permanently installed and configured *correctly* without crashing my SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either a Google search or a search of [support.microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com) for the knowledge base article number will reveal the reason for it being installed.

For example, KB976098 is [December 2009 cumulative time zone update for Microsoft Windows operating systems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976098). So if you search for each of the patches that were installed you might find one that's to do with SQL Express.

Beyond that I can't really offer anything else.

Comment: None of them have anything to do with SQL Server.